# The least intrusive and most elegant for removing \documentclass?

Tags: beamer, programming, input

Here is the context: I have a file named (say) `00.tex`, which I use in the following elaborate way.

Compiling the file, generates auxiliary tex files, which in turn execute `\include{00.tex}`. The motivation is that the auxiliary files are named

```
slides-1-1-introduction.tex
handouts-1-1-introduction.tex
slides-1-2-administration.tex
handouts-1-2-administration.tex
...
slides-2-1-landing.tex
handouts-2-1-landing.tex
slides-2-2-speech.tex
handouts-2-2-speech.tex
```

each of these represents a portion and a perspective on a large course divided into sections and subsection.

Now, file `00.tex` must have `\documentclass` since it is compiled separately, either for generating the auxiliary files, or for generating the full presentation. On the other hand, this `\documentclass` must not be there if it is included from other files.

To complicate things further, the `\documentclass` is not necessarily the first command, e.g., you must declare options to classes before issuing it.

I can think of trick involving redefinition of `\documenclass` from within the auxiliary files but I trust this crow'ds have more elegant ideas.

Comment: Perhaps the package `standalone` is what you are looking for.  Also see the category 'subdocs' on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/topic/subdocs).  But what do you mean by 'you must declare options to classes before issuing it'?  Who must?  Do you mean simply that you *are* doing that?

Comment: or you can read `standalone` class manual :)

Comment: One can compile a document from the command line using `pdflatex \documentclass{article}\input{abc}`...

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the package `subfiles`? With this package you can have one main file (`00.tex`) with the preamble and the documentclass of your preference (beamer) and other subfiles with `\documentclass[00.tex]{subfiles}` so they use the same preamble and documentclass as `00.tex` but can be compiled standalone. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: The issue here is that the list of files is not fixed. It is generated dynamically from commands such as `\unit{Fit the First: THE LANDING}{landing}` which means introduce a section entitled "Fit the First: THE LANDING" which resides in a file named `landing`.

Comment: `Subfile looks like a great idea. I will see if the package can cope with the automatic generation of auxiliary files, and the rest of the baggage beamer and zillion of other packages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution is to not put the `\documentclass` in the file you include. If `11.tex` does not have `\documentclass` then you can `\include` it without problem, To make a standalone version you just need one additional file `11-only.tex` that looks like

```
 \documentclass{whatever}
 \usepackage{whatever}
 \begin{document}
 \input{11}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: If you use (x)emacs, you can tell AUCTeX to process just the region or the file you are looking at. It has its glitches (cross references usually get totally lost), but is fine for previewing.

Answer (score 0):

I provide this answer for the benefit of people who might be in need of composing slides for a large course. To allow the author to concentrate on content rather than on familiar or not so familiar commands, the main file, `00.tex` includes only the absolute minimum:

```
\usepackage{00}
\input{00-nesting.tex}

\ifdef\unitFileName\relax{
% Feel free to change, if you wish, for some reason, to 
  % use the main file for \include{}ing one or more files.
  \includeonly{nothing} 
}

\title{my title}
\institute{where I am}

\begin{document}
\fullTOC
\UNIT{Introduction}{introduction}{introduction}
  \unit{Administration}{administration}
  \unit{Motivation}{motivation}
  \unit{History of Programming Languages}{history}
  \unit{Programming Paradigms}{paradigms}
  \unit{Syntax Specification}{syntax}
  \unit{Syntactical Elements}{elements}
  \unit{Programming Language Design}{design}
  \unit{Hello, World!}{hello}

\UNIT{Values and Types}{values-and-types}
  \unit{Value Systems}{value-systems}
  \unit{Why Types}{why-types}
  \unit{Type Constructors}{type-constructors}
  \unit{Atomic Types}{atomic}
\UNIT{Advanced Typing}{advanced-typing}
  \unit{Classification of Type Systems}{classification}
  \unit{Structural vs.\ Nominal Typing}{structural}
  \unit{Polymorphism}{polymorphism}
\UNIT{Storage}{storage}
 \unit{Storage Models}{models}
 \unit{Arrays}{arrays}
 \unit{Variables' Life time}{variables-lifetime}
 \unit{Automatic Memory Management}{automatic-memory-management}
 \unit{Functional Abstractions}{functional}
 \unit{Value vs.\ Reference Semantics}{reference-vs-value-semantics}
 \unit{Run Time Type Information}{run-time-type-information}
\UNIT{Miscellaneous}{misc}
 \unit{Commands}{commands}
    \subsubsection{Recursive Structure of Commands} 
    \subsubsection{Atomic Commands in \protect\Java, \protect\Pascal and \protect\CC} 
    \subsubsection{Command Constructors} 
    \subsubsection{Sequencers}
 \unit{Definitions and Declarations}{declarations}
 \unit{Management of Names Spaces in \protect\Java}{name-spaces-in-java}
 \unit{Compiling, Loading and Running \protect\Java Programs}{compiling-and-running-java}
\end{document}
```

The `00-nesting.tex` (temporary name) has most of the ugly stuff. (Take note that this is a snapshot of the current, in progress, version)

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatother

\newcommand\handoutsHeaderFileName{-handouts-header.tex}
\newcommand\slidesHeaderFileName{-slides-header.tex}

\WarningFilter{latex}{Overwriting file}
\typeout{Generating common header file for handouts (that is, in beamer's "handout" mode): './handout-header.tex'}

\begin{filecontents}{\handoutsHeaderFileName}
  \PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}
  \PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks,final}{hyperref}
  \PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
  \documentclass[t]{beamer}
  \input{00.tex}
\end{filecontents}

\typeout{Generating common header file for slides (that is, in beamer's "beamer" mode): './slides-header.tex'}
\begin{filecontents}{-slides-header.tex}
  \PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}
  \PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks,final}{hyperref}
  \PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}
  \documentclass[t]{beamer}
  \hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\end{filecontents}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\isincluded}[1]{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@partsw   
    \@tempswafalse
    \edef\reserved@b{#1}%
    \@for\reserved@a:=\@partlist\do
      {\ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswatrue\fi}%
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}

\newcommand\unit[2]{%
  \isincluded{#2}{\fullTOC}{}%
  \subsection{#1}%
  \CreateIncludingFileSubsection{#1}{#2}%
  \include{#2}%
  \emptyTOC
}
\newcommand\UNIT[2]{%
%  \isincluded{#2}{\fullTOC}{}%
  \section{#1}%
  \CreateIncludingFileSection{#1}{#2}%
  \include{#2}%
%  \emptyTOC
}

  % 1 = kind (handouts/slides)  
  % 2 = section, 
  % 3 = subsection, 
  % 4 = file name, 
  % 5 = Header file name, 
  % 6 = Title. 
  \newcommand\toFile[6]{% 
      \immediate\openout\tempfile=#1-#2-#3-#4.tex%
      \immediate\write\tempfile{\@percentchar\space Hi! I am a file which was automatically generated on \today;} 
      \immediate\write\tempfile{\@percentchar\space Any changes you should make to me, are very ephemeral in nature. Sooner}
      \immediate\write\tempfile{\@percentchar\space rather than later, they will be overriden by the program that generated}
      \immediate\write\tempfile{\@percentchar\space me. May the odds be ever in your favor!}
      \immediate\write\tempfile{\noexpand\input{#5}}%
      \immediate\write\tempfile{\unexpanded{\def\unitFileName{#4}}}%
      \immediate\write\tempfile{\unexpanded{\def\unitTitle{#6}}}%
      \immediate\write\tempfile{\unexpanded{\includeonly{\unitFileName}}}%
      \immediate\write\tempfile{\noexpand\input{00.tex}}%
      \immediate\closeout\tempfile
  }
  \newcommand\makeHandouts[4]{\toFile{handouts}{#1}{#2}{#3}{\handoutsHeaderFileName}{#4}}
  \newcommand\makeSlides[4]{\toFile{slides}{#1}{#2}{#3}{\slidesHeaderFileName}{#4}}
  \newcommand\makeInclusion[4]{\makeHandouts{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\makeSlides{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}


\ifdef{\unitFileName}{}
\ifdef\unitFileName{
  \typeout{LaTeXing a specific section/subsection entitled "\unitTitle", residing in file \unitFileName}
  \newcommand\CreateIncludingFileSubsection[2]{\relax}%
  \newcommand\CreateIncludingFileSection[2]{\relax}%
}{
  \typeout{LaTeXing the full file \jobname}
  \newwrite\tempfile
  \newcommand\CreateIncludingFileSubsection[2]{\makeInclusion{\thesection}{\thesubsection}{#2}{#1}}
  \newcommand\CreateIncludingFileSection[2]{\makeInclusion{\thesection}{0}{#2}{#1}}
  \input{\slidesHeaderFileName}
}
```