# docmute does not work: only the first \input takes effect and the other ones are ignored

Tags: tables

My scenario is as follows:

- `mytabclass` is a document class only for defining macros to create a table.
- the body of any input file inheriting from `mytabclass` can only contain some rows. No other typesetting items other than rows can be defined inside the document body.
- As `docmute` package is loaded in `mytabclass`, any input file inheriting from  `mytabclass` can also import other input files which are also inheriting from  `mytabclass`.

### Minimal Working Example

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mytabclass.cls}
\ProvidesClass{mytabclass}[2015/05/14 this is my table class]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[]{article}

\RequirePackage{longtable,array,etoolbox}
\newcounter{counter}


\newcolumntype\specifier{%
    |
    *2{>{\centering\stepcounter{counter}\thecounter}m{1cm}
        |>{\centering}m{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
        |}
}


\def\row[#1]#2{%
        & \parbox[c][0.2\dimexpr\textheight-6\arrayrulewidth-\topskip\relax][c]{\linewidth}{\centering #1 \par \vspace{15pt} #2}
        \ifodd\value{counter}
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
            \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
        {&}{\tabularnewline\hline}
}


\pagestyle{empty}
\AfterEndPreamble{%
  \begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline
}
\preto\enddocument{\ifodd\value{counter}\omit\tabularnewline\cline{1-2}\fi\end{longtable}}


\RequirePackage{docmute}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\endinput
% mytabclass.cls
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{chapter-1.tex}
\documentclass[12pt]{mytabclass}
\begin{document}
\row[A]{B}
\row[C]{D}
\row[E]{F}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{chapter-2.tex}
\documentclass[12pt]{mytabclass}
\begin{document}
\row[G]{H}
\row[I]{J}
\row[K]{L}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{mytabclass}


\begin{document}

\input{chapter-1}
\input{chapter-2}

\end{document}
```

### Problems

The MWE above should produce a table with rows imported from both `chapter-1` and `chapter-2`. Unfortunately, if you compile my MWE above, you will notice that `chapter-2` will not be imported. What cause this issue and how to solve it?

### Notes

- The real scenario adopts "divide and conquer" philosophy to make the development phase faster. It means each chapter must be a compilabe input file. It contains a huge number of rows. If I am working only on chapter 6, for example, I just need to compile this input file. If I put all rows (from all chapters) in a single main input file, then the time will be significantly wasted during the development of a single chapter.
- When I compile the main input file in the final phase (after all chapters are properly developed), I want  just a single table sharing the same counter.

Comment: Anything after `\end{document}` is ignored. Your included files contains a `\end{document}`, so this is really the end marker of the document. A second `\begin{document}` or whatever has no effect

Comment: Is my problem sexy enough?

Comment: I think you should edit your code above and introduce some separator between the code for the class and the MWE. At the moment `\documentclass...` is inside the class file ;-)  ... Oh, I just saw, you're using `docmute`

Comment: Inside `filecontents` write only the body of the documents.

Comment: But you can create all of the required files on the fly with the given MWE. And `docmute` does a magic such that `\input` only takes anything inside `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`:-)

Comment: Why complicate things including complete document and then using fragile packages to make that work, rather than simply inputting the body of the documents?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I'll try to figure out the problem, but I agree with your statement about the complications here ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Because it is just an MWE. The real scenario contains a large number of rows for each chapter input file. Each chapter must be compilable so I can see the result quickly rather than put all rows in a single main input file. It is what I call as "divide and conquer" approach.

Comment: There are _lots_ of ways of having a combined document and being able to process each chapter separately, not least the standard `\includeonly` all the methods that involve inputting files that have `\documentclass` are inherently fragile, and combining that with a package that hooks typesetting into end{document} is just asking for problems, it would be possible to make it work but I would never do this.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155732/the-least-intrusive-and-most-elegant-for-removing-documentclass/155744#155744

Comment: I don't know docmute but I implemented a similar system with standalone: Every file could be compiled on its own and input in files that combined them into larger parts -- but I didn't try to add a longtable around everything.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am not so happy with commenting and uncommenting `\input`in the main input file every time I work for a single chapter. :-)

Comment: @FriendlyGhost: I think, that the wrapping of documents into longtable environment screws up the whole environment grouping system and  the `docmute@nestinglevel` counter is not correctly maintained

Comment: @FriendlyGhost there is no need to use comments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Editing a single `\input` is basically similar to commenting and uncommenting 2 `\input` of several `\input`s. This is what I want to avoid. It sounds I am too lazy? No. Because it also makes me rename the produced output from `main.pdf` to `chapter-6.pdf`, for example, when just using a single `main.tex` during the development unless I let the previous compilation get overwritten. :-)

Comment: If I were doing this I'd remove _all_ the complication of hacking document and simply have the longtables in separate files starting `\begin{longtable}`  your main document then \include each one and you have separate per-chapter documents that just \input one table so no editing is required at all, just process the relevant file. No comments no editing and no fragile macros that break each other if used in combination:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But I need a single table sharing the same counter in the main input file.

Comment: OK so just move the `longtable` to your top level files, and just have the rows in the table files.

Comment: @FriendlyGhost I told you not to patch `\document` or `\enddocument`. `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments I would not patch `document` either to add `longtable` or to allow it to be included. Simply store the body of the table in separate files to be included into suitable wrapper documents.

Running latex on the main file will make a combined table, running it on (say) `chapter-2.tex` will just make the rows for that chapter,

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mytabclass.cls}
\ProvidesClass{mytabclass}[2015/05/14 this is my table class]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[]{article}

\RequirePackage{longtable,array,etoolbox}
\newcounter{counter}

\newcommand\finalline{%
\ifodd\value{counter}\omit\tabularnewline\cline{1-2}\fi
}

\newcolumntype\specifier{%
    |
    *2{>{\centering\stepcounter{counter}\thecounter}m{1cm}
        |>{\centering}m{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
        |}
}


\def\row[#1]#2{%
        & \parbox[c][0.2\dimexpr\textheight-6\arrayrulewidth-\topskip\relax][c]{\linewidth}{\centering #1 \par \vspace{15pt} #2}
        \ifodd\value{counter}
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
            \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
        {&}{\tabularnewline\hline}
}


\pagestyle{empty}

\endinput
% mytabclass.cls
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{chapter-1.tex}
\documentclass[12pt]{mytabclass}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline
\input{chapter-1.tbl}
\finalline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{chapter-1.tbl}
\row[A]{B}
\row[C]{D}
\row[E]{F}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{chapter-2.tex}
\documentclass[12pt]{mytabclass}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline
\input{chapter-2.tbl}
\finalline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{chapter-2.tbl}
\row[G]{H}
\row[I]{J}
\row[K]{L}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{mytabclass}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{\specifier}\hline
\input{chapter-1.tbl}
\input{chapter-2.tbl}
\finalline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make my life much simpler, I will do the following. It is partially based on David Carlisle's solution.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{template.tex}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable,array,etoolbox}
\newcounter{counter}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype\specifier{%
    |
    *2{>{\centering\stepcounter{counter}\thecounter}m{1cm}
        |>{\centering}m{0.5\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth\relax}
        |}
}

\def\row[#1]#2{%
        & \parbox[c][0.2\dimexpr\textheight-6\arrayrulewidth-\topskip\relax][c]{\linewidth}{\centering #1 \par \vspace{15pt} #2}
        \ifodd\value{counter}
            \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
            \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
        {&}{\tabularnewline\hline}
}

\newcommand\finalline{%
\ifodd\value{counter}\omit\tabularnewline\cline{1-2}\fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{\specifier}
\hline
\input{\InputFileName}
\finalline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}



\begin{filecontents*}{selector.tex}
echo off
rem %1 input file without extension
pdflatex -jobname="%~1" "\def\InputFileName{%~1}\input{template}"
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{cmd /c rename selector.tex selector.bat && cmd /c del selector.tex}


\begin{filecontents*}{chapter-1.tex}
\row[A]{B}
\row[C]{D}
\row[E]{F}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{chapter-2.tex}
\row[G]{H}
\row[I]{J}
\row[K]{L}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{filecontents*}{main.tex}
\input{Chapter-1}
\input{Chapter-2}
\end{filecontents*}





% simulating

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\def\filename{main}

% creating

\immediate\write18{selector \filename}

% verifying
\includepdf[pages=-]{\filename}
\end{document}
```